# $\int\log(x+1)$ = something containing $\log(x+1)$?

Tags: logarithms

For $\int\log(x+1)$, http://calculus-calculator.com/integral/ returns

$$-x+(x+1)\log(x+1)-1+c$$

The output contains the input. Does that mean the function is recursive?

Comment: Just because the integral of a function contains the function why would that mean the function is recursive?

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes, OK. That was easy.

Comment: What's your definition of recursive function? @mjc

Comment: @jacopoburelli A function whose definition/output contains the whole function/input, e.g. $f(x)=gf(x)$. I think the log question was a simple confusion, now solved.